# Issue with custom webkit scrollbar

Tags: css, scrollbar

[image]

I'm making a custom scrollbar with css but as you can see in the picture the corner of the scrollbar track isn't like what I need, I have tried border radius for bottom right and top right but no luck, any help would be appreciated!

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: url("/assets/scrollbar.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 9px 150px;
    display: block;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    background: grey;
  }
```

Comment: Can you post your full code or make a codepen?

Comment: Hello @AnikethMalyala my code involved the scrollbar are all the css code I showed above, there is nothing else, and I will add a code pen soon, thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a guy in my team, we managed to solve the issue by adding the background to webkit scrollbar track.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the perspective property of css to rotate it according to the picture on the right.

This code will help you to understand.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    .div1{
        border: 1px solid blue;
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        perspective: 200px; /* Defines how far the object is */
    }

    .div2{
        transform-style: preserve-3d; /* Rotatingthe div as a 3d object */
        transform: rotateY(45deg);

        height: 60%;

        display: flex; /* Flexbox for centering the text */
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;

        background-color: grey;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="div1">
        Div 1
        <div class="div2">
            Div 2
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope you understood. Check out [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_perspective.asp) for more. Please feel free to ask in the comments if you need more explanation.